# Using Google Sheets to bulk collect the number of Google Search results count for given keywords

Tags: google-sheets, regex, microsoft-excel, importhtml

I need to bulk check the number of Google Search results count for given keywords by using  Google Sheets or Microsoft excel

For example,
ocean is About 2,960,000,000 results
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is from six years ago, but from my testing, it seems to not have changed.

> Google has lately been blocking search requests made from both Apps Scripts and Google Sheets though the requests are made from one of their own IPs. They probably do this to prevent scraping.

So you cannot use `IMPORTHTML` nor `IMPORTXML`(which would be the way one would do it) to obtain that number. You might need to reach out to actual webscraping to get your goal and copy that data unto your sheets.

[Check the answer out by Amit Agarwal.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37560985/19171356)

Comment: could u please suggest one of these webscraping  to check bulk collect the number of Google Search results

Comment: I'm personally not well versed in web scraping, so I can't recommend anything with confidence. [But do check this blog post out.](https://serpmaster.com/blog/how-to-scrape-google/)